# Survey for each list item

Tags: list, workflow, custom-list, custom-form, survey

I would like to create an environment where an employee can add an idea to a custom list of ideas.
Then I would like other employees to be able to rank each idea.

How can I create such a thing?

I thought of creating a list a workflow to connect each list item to a different survey (Possible?).

Any Ideas?

Thanks,
Doron.

Answer (score 4):

What you could to is just create a OOTB custom list, change the `Title` field to "New Idea" or something relevant and then enable ratings for the list from List Settings > Rating Settings.

Enable it to Yes and select Star ratings and voila! Users can now rate the item/idea on a scale of 1-5 stars.

[image]

If you wanna take it further from there, you could set up a Survey list (or another custom list) and add a lookup column to the Idea list where they can select to respond to any of the ideas with a comment.

[image]

Comment: Great use of OOTB functionality